# Cant connect Java to MariaDB

Tags: java, mariadb

I cant connect  java to MariaDB .I saw all similar questions answers but none has solved my problem. Here is my code :

```
/** To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project
 *   Properties.  * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates 
 * and open the template in the editor.  
 */
package mariadbtest; 

import java.sql.*;


/**
 * 
 * @author AAAA  
 */ 
public class MariaDBTest {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args){  
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            String url = "jdbc:MariaDB://localhost:3306/customer"; // url to access the DB
            String user = "root";
            String pwd="password";
     
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pwd);
     
            System.out.println("Connected to MariaDB");
        } 
        catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("SQL Exception: "+ e.toString()); 
        } 
        catch (ClassNotFoundException cE) {
            System.out.println("Class Not Found Exception: "+ cE.toString()); 
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception: "+ ex.toString()); 
        }

        // TODO code application logic here
    }
}
```

Note the following :

- I am using the connector mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.
- I have the latest java version.
- MariaDB version is 10.3.27.
- I have copied the connector to the lib directory in java folder in program files .
- I have added the connector JAR file to my project through properties --> Libraries --> Add JAR/Folder.
- MariaDB has the service name MariaDB.
- The database name is customer.

error :
SQL Exception: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:MariaDB://localhost:3306/customer
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)

Comment: Maybe try using a [MariaDB Connector](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/about-mariadb-connector-j/)

Comment: @DevilsHnd Do I use the same steps for inserting the connector as mentioned in the question ?

Comment: Read the information contained within the provided link above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is that you are using a MySQL Connector/J JDBC driver with a URL that it doesn't recognize.  This URL

```
    jdbc:MariaDB://localhost:3306/customer
```

says to look for a driver from a "MariaDB" provider.  But apparently the MySQL drivers don't advertise themselves (via SPI) as being MariaDB drivers.

### Solution

First of you should get rid of this:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
```

It is not needed, and you are hard-wiring a driver classname into your code.  Get rid of the associated exception handler clauses too.  (This is all [Voodoo Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voodoo_programming) stuff.  It might have been needed 20 years ago ... but not anymore.)

You can fix the driver resolution problem in two ways:

1. Change the URL to this:

   ```
   jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/customer
   ```

   According to the [MariaDB documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/), the MySQL Connector/J driver is compatible with MariaDB.  But use of "MariaDB" in the JDBC url  not mentioned in the MySQL Connector/J documentation.
2. Switch to the [MariaDB Connector/J driver](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/about-mariadb-connector-j/).  According to the documentation, this should support

   ```
   jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/customer
   ```

   or

   ```
   jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/customer
   ```

It is not clear from the docs whether the case of the "protocol" part matters.  However, syntax specification in the MariaDB doc uses "mariadb" not "MariaDB", so I would recommend lower-case for stylistic consistency.